# As a result of the Euclidean distance many images are mistakenly identified as identical

Tags: python, sql, mariadb, image-recognition, imagehash

Sorry for my bad english, i have a small database that contains hashes of photos,
when I try to find similar photos to the one below:

[image]

for which the following hash was calculated: "0f3f2764ecc482c2" using the method average_hash()

```
imagehash.average_hash(Image.open(imagePath))
```

The system finds a very large number of collisions, below is an example of photos that were identified as completely identical:

[image]

[image]

**The table in which I store hashes of photos:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS photos(id_photo BIGINT PRIMARY  KEY,  photo_hash TEXT,  FOREIGN KEY (id_photo) REFERENCES users (id));
```

**Adding hash:**

```
cur.execute('''INSERT INTO photos(id_photo, photo_hash) VALUES(%s, %s)''', id, str(result_image_recognition['photo_hash'])])
```

SQL Query by which I calculate the Euclidean distance between my hash and stored hashes:

```
SELECT id_photo, BIT_COUNT(photo_hash ^ '0f3f2764ecc482c2') FROM photos;
```

The photos table contains 7889 photos, 959 of them are mistakenly determined by this query as completely identical (Euclidean distance is 0). About a week I can not solve this problem please someone help me.

Comment: You are using 64-bit hashes. I would try with 160-bit hashes at least using SHA1 or even SHA256-512 to reduce collisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the hex strings to integers before doing xor operations

```sql
SELECT id_photo, BIT_COUNT(CONV(photo_hash, 16, 10) ^ CONV('0f3f2764ecc482c2', 16, 10)) FROM photos;
```

because all strings the first character of which is not 1-9 are converted to 0.

```
mysql> select 'abc' ^ 'def'; # -> 0
mysql> select CONV('abc', 16, 10) ^ CONV('def', 16, 10);  # -> 1875
```

Comment: Hello again)

Сan you please tell me the easiest way to compare two faces in python?

I want to get(from photo) and store biometrics of the faces in my database and then using SQL Query to search for similar faces? 

i found the module for python 'face_recognition'  but nothing worked, then I asked the question here)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69606556/%d0%a1ompare-two-faces-using-python3-module-face-recognition

but I'm afraid the person who answered me did not understand)