# Сompare two faces using python3 module face_recognition?

Tags: python-3.x, face-recognition, image-recognition

sorry for my bad english.
I am trying to compare two faces using python3 module 'face_recognition'

here is an example of calculating euclidean distance in python

> pdist([vector1, vector2], 'euclidean')

I want to calculate euclidean distance only in SQL query, because all faces(theirs vectors) will be stored in my database, but I do not know how to do this with a SQL query.

**Information:**

MariaDB version: **10.5.11**

Python: **3.9.2**

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import face_recognition
import mysql.connector as mysql


def get_image_hash(image):
    # Open image
    img = face_recognition.load_image_file(image)

    # Save as black
    #img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Get vector
    vector = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]

    vector = (str(vector),)
    
    return vector


# Open DB
conn = mysql.connect(
  host = '127.0.0.1',
  user = 'user',
  passwd = 'password'
)

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SHOW DATABASES")          

# Check if db 'test' already exist
db_found = False
for db in cur:
    if 'test' in db:
        db_found = True


if not db_found:
    cur.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test;")
    conn.commit()
    
cur.execute("USE test;")


cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS faces(id_face BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, face_hash TEXT)""")                            
                                         
new_image = get_image_hash('test.jpg')

# Add face(array) in DB
cur.execute('''INSERT INTO faces (face_hash) VALUES(%s)''', new_image)
conn.commit()


# Upload a picture for search
find_me_image = get_image_hash('findme.jpg')
#print('d: ', find_me_image[0])

# How should i compare these two arrays in my SQL query to find a similar face?
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM faces WHERE ..... ;")

cur.close()

print('find_me_image: ', str(find_me_image))
print('new_image: ', str(new_image))
```

Result:

```
Find_me_image: ('[-0.04221933  0.04460172  0.10287622 -0.14319997 -0.13808066  0.00552465\n -0.04414323 -0.07157505  0.23200855 -0.12091423  0.16892464 -0.16992114\n -0.2487883   0.09141497 -0.14198568  0.1824664  -0.11484738 -0.1130986\n -0.14396232 -0.06075872 -0.00201617  0.07473749 -0.01706937  0.05610432\n -0.11021845 -0.30173326 -0.02712429 -0.10394925 -0.05155517 -0.21909578\n  0.03083897  0.16680503 -0.09715255 -0.0407755  -0.01714687  0.08432341\n -0.01913652 -0.13662203  0.21924476  0.04394831 -0.20848413 -0.03259828\n  0.04784738  0.30321479  0.22730266 -0.02372641 -0.01165112 -0.12765107\n  0.13877977 -0.3403039   0.0424962   0.10813272  0.0511388   0.12078771\n  0.04942191 -0.13038178  0.02736722  0.15339687 -0.24367541  0.10453884\n  0.13450858 -0.09997959  0.01744595 -0.10602434  0.2614505   0.10681546\n -0.12075276 -0.12065229  0.195976   -0.11606392 -0.0447496   0.08198876\n -0.13573587 -0.18409243 -0.19127932  0.01680213  0.35644779  0.16652581\n -0.12988403 -0.00341757 -0.15569599 -0.09128557 -0.03799717  0.09235845\n  0.06296059 -0.07972728  0.00744779  0.07452074  0.23394027 -0.0726112\n -0.00072305  0.2978259  -0.01452125 -0.06529554 -0.08694689  0.01903715\n -0.14941891  0.10714116 -0.1096215   0.00143995  0.00146057  0.00348109\n  0.06795555  0.10826397 -0.18627991  0.21965174 -0.04136307 -0.01491791\n  0.03774849 -0.07495191 -0.03808937 -0.02331351  0.29242265 -0.23740929\n  0.13265632  0.1274993   0.17672779  0.11845816  0.01477844  0.07670261\n  0.11437597 -0.03779818 -0.21296507  0.03480547  0.06180557 -0.01749492\n -0.023851    0.11586148]',)
New_image:  ('[-0.04221933  0.04460172  0.10287622 -0.14319997 -0.13808066  0.00552465\n -0.04414323 -0.07157505  0.23200855 -0.12091423  0.16892464 -0.16992114\n -0.2487883   0.09141497 -0.14198568  0.1824664  -0.11484738 -0.1130986\n -0.14396232 -0.06075872 -0.00201617  0.07473749 -0.01706937  0.05610432\n -0.11021845 -0.30173326 -0.02712429 -0.10394925 -0.05155517 -0.21909578\n  0.03083897  0.16680503 -0.09715255 -0.0407755  -0.01714687  0.08432341\n -0.01913652 -0.13662203  0.21924476  0.04394831 -0.20848413 -0.03259828\n  0.04784738  0.30321479  0.22730266 -0.02372641 -0.01165112 -0.12765107\n  0.13877977 -0.3403039   0.0424962   0.10813272  0.0511388   0.12078771\n  0.04942191 -0.13038178  0.02736722  0.15339687 -0.24367541  0.10453884\n  0.13450858 -0.09997959  0.01744595 -0.10602434  0.2614505   0.10681546\n -0.12075276 -0.12065229  0.195976   -0.11606392 -0.0447496   0.08198876\n -0.13573587 -0.18409243 -0.19127932  0.01680213  0.35644779  0.16652581\n -0.12988403 -0.00341757 -0.15569599 -0.09128557 -0.03799717  0.09235845\n  0.06296059 -0.07972728  0.00744779  0.07452074  0.23394027 -0.0726112\n -0.00072305  0.2978259  -0.01452125 -0.06529554 -0.08694689  0.01903715\n -0.14941891  0.10714116 -0.1096215   0.00143995  0.00146057  0.00348109\n  0.06795555  0.10826397 -0.18627991  0.21965174 -0.04136307 -0.01491791\n  0.03774849 -0.07495191 -0.03808937 -0.02331351  0.29242265 -0.23740929\n  0.13265632  0.1274993   0.17672779  0.11845816  0.01477844  0.07670261\n  0.11437597 -0.03779818 -0.21296507  0.03480547  0.06180557 -0.01749492\n -0.023851    0.11586148]',)
```

New:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import json
import face_recognition
import mysql.connector as mysql

# DB
conn = mysql.connect(
  host = 'localhost',
  user = '',
  passwd = ''
)


def load(str_data):
    str_data = str_data.replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
    result = []
    for i, line in enumerate(str_data.split("\n")):
        result.append([])
        for element in line.replace("  ", " ").split(" "):
            try:
                result[i].append(float(element))
            except ValueError:
                pass
    return result
    

def distance(model, test):
    distance = 0
    for i, line in enumerate(model):
        dist_line = 0
        for j, element in enumerate(line):
            dist_line += (element - test[i][j]) ** 2
        distance += dist_line ** 0.5
    return distance
    
  
def get_image_hash(image):
    # Open image
    img = face_recognition.load_image_file(image)

    # Save as black
    #img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Get vector
    vector = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]

    # We can save only iterable object
    vector = (str(vector),)
    
    return vector


cur = conn.cursor(buffered=True)
cur.execute("SHOW DATABASES")          


# Check if db 'test' already exist
db_found = False
for db in cur:
    if 'test' in db:
        db_found = True

if not db_found:
    cur.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test;")
    conn.commit()
    
cur.execute("USE test;")
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS faces(id_face BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, face_hash TEXT)""")                            
                                         
# Add face in DB
new_image = get_image_hash('test.jpg')


print('new_image debug: ', new_image)


cur.execute('''INSERT INTO faces (face_hash) VALUES(%s)''', new_image)
conn.commit()


# Find added face
find_me_image = get_image_hash('findme.jpg')
print('debug find_me_image: ', find_me_image)



# Get data from DB
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM faces;")
face_data = cur.fetchall()


# Check
for x in face_data:
  print('1: ', load(find_me_image[0]))
  print('2: ', load(x[1]))
  
  # x[1] == row face_hash
  compare_result = distance(load(find_me_image[0]), load(x[1]))

#print('Result: ', compare_result)

# Got error
'''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Desktop/parser_steam/image_recognition/test/./test.py", line 102, in <module>
    compare_result = distance(load(find_me_image[0]), load(x[1]))
  File "/home/user/Desktop/parser_steam/image_recognition/test/./test.py", line 35, in distance
    dist_line += (element - test[i][j]) ** 2
IndexError: list index out of range
'''


cur.close()
```

Error:
[image: Different number of elements in arrays]

Comment: `print(Find_me_image == New_image)` -> `True` 
The distance is 0 here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need!

```
import json


def load(str_data):
    str_data = str_data.replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
    result = []
    for i, line in enumerate(str_data.split("\n")):
        result.append([])
        for element in line.replace("  ", " ").split(" "):
            try:
                result[i].append(float(element))
            except ValueError:
                pass
    return result


def distance(model, test):
    distance = 0
    for i, line in enumerate(model):
        dist_line = 0
        for j, element in enumerate(line):
            dist_line += (element - test[i][j]) ** 2
        distance += dist_line ** 0.5
    return distance


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Find_me_image = '[-0.04221933  0.04460172  0.10287622 -0.14319997 -0.13808066  0.00552465\n -0.04414323 -0.07157505  0.23200855 -0.12091423  0.16892464 -0.16992114\n -0.2487883   0.09141497 -0.14198568  0.1824664  -0.11484738 -0.1130986\n -0.14396232 -0.06075872 -0.00201617  0.07473749 -0.01706937  0.05610432\n -0.11021845 -0.30173326 -0.02712429 -0.10394925 -0.05155517 -0.21909578\n  0.03083897  0.16680503 -0.09715255 -0.0407755  -0.01714687  0.08432341\n -0.01913652 -0.13662203  0.21924476  0.04394831 -0.20848413 -0.03259828\n  0.04784738  0.30321479  0.22730266 -0.02372641 -0.01165112 -0.12765107\n  0.13877977 -0.3403039   0.0424962   0.10813272  0.0511388   0.12078771\n  0.04942191 -0.13038178  0.02736722  0.15339687 -0.24367541  0.10453884\n  0.13450858 -0.09997959  0.01744595 -0.10602434  0.2614505   0.10681546\n -0.12075276 -0.12065229  0.195976   -0.11606392 -0.0447496   0.08198876\n -0.13573587 -0.18409243 -0.19127932  0.01680213  0.35644779  0.16652581\n -0.12988403 -0.00341757 -0.15569599 -0.09128557 -0.03799717  0.09235845\n  0.06296059 -0.07972728  0.00744779  0.07452074  0.23394027 -0.0726112\n -0.00072305  0.2978259  -0.01452125 -0.06529554 -0.08694689  0.01903715\n -0.14941891  0.10714116 -0.1096215   0.00143995  0.00146057  0.00348109\n  0.06795555  0.10826397 -0.18627991  0.21965174 -0.04136307 -0.01491791\n  0.03774849 -0.07495191 -0.03808937 -0.02331351  0.29242265 -0.23740929\n  0.13265632  0.1274993   0.17672779  0.11845816  0.01477844  0.07670261\n  0.11437597 -0.03779818 -0.21296507  0.03480547  0.06180557 -0.01749492\n -0.023851    0.11586148]'
    New_image = '[-0.04221933  0.04460172  0.10287622 -0.14319997 -0.13808064  0.00552465\n -0.04414323 -0.07157505  0.23200855 -0.12091423  0.16892464 -0.16992114\n -0.2487883   0.09141497 -0.14198568  0.18246  -0.11484738 -0.1130986\n -0.14396232 -0.06075872 -0.0020117  0.07473749 -0.01706937  0.05610432\n -0.11021845 -0.30173326 -0.02712429 -0.10394925 -0.05155517 -0.21909578\n  0.03083897  0.16680503 -0.09715255 -0.0407755  -0.01714687  0.08432341\n -0.01913652 -0.13662203  0.21924476  0.04394831 -0.20848413 -0.03259828\n  0.04784738  0.30321479  0.22730266 -0.02372641 -0.0116112 -0.12765107\n  0.13877977 -0.3403039   0.0424962   0.10813272  0.0511388   0.12078771\n  0.04942191 -0.13038178  0.02736722  0.15339687 -0.24367541  0.10453884\n  0.13450858 -0.09997959  0.01744595 -0.10602434  0.2614505   0.10681546\n -0.12075276 -0.12065229  0.195976   -0.11606392 -0.0447496   0.08198876\n -0.1357387 -0.18409243 -0.19127932  0.01680213  0.35644779  0.16652581\n -0.12988403 -0.00341757 -0.15569599 -0.09128557 -0.03799717  0.09235845\n  0.06296059 -0.07972728  0.00744779  0.07452074  0.23394027 -0.0726112\n -0.00072305  0.2978259  -0.01452125 -0.06529554 -0.08694689  0.0193715\n -0.14941891  0.10714116 -0.1096215   0.00143995  0.00146057  0.00348109\n  0.06795555  0.10826397 -0.18627991  0.21965174 -0.04136307 -0.01491791\n  0.03774849 -0.07495191 -0.03808937 -0.02331351  0.29242265 -0.23740929\n  0.13265632  0.1274993   0.1762779  0.11845816  0.01477844  0.07670261\n  0.11437597 -0.03779818 -0.21296507  0.03480547  0.0618057 -0.01749492\n -0.023851    0.1158648]'

    print(distance(
        load(Find_me_image),
        load(New_image)
    ))
```

You need first to convert your datas using `load` function. Then calculate distance using `distance` function.
As your datas are the sames, I modify `New_image` datas to test the function.

Comment: thanks for the help!!

If i understood everything correctly at first I will have get ALL(I will have a lot of them " >1000000") the hashes from the database, and then convert and compare them in python?  

I will store all vectors of images in the database(I don’t know yet what type data for this i have to use) and I need to calculate the Euclidean distance between the vector of my image and all the vectors that are in the database using only SQL query.

Comment: No, you can run the process one by one in order to not overflow your RAM with 1000000 examples.
The arrays are not hashs but arrays and you should not store multiples datas inside one database, name your columns.
Then you can have a look on triggers on database to run this distance calculation every new face input in the DB.
But your question is about get datas and calcul distance. Don t forget to green check if answered!

Comment: Hello Vincent!
please can  you check(if you have free time) why when i calculating euclidean distance between lists I get an error:    dist_line += (element - test[i][j]) ** 2

I added new code to post.

Comment: Hey, you need a 2D array to the function works here you give 1 D array

Comment: Bonjour! I found the error, but I do not understand how to fix it.

The error is that the last array of one photo contains 2 elements and the other 4 elements. can you try to run it on your own?

Comment: There is no mathematical solution to find a distance between 2 datas that are not equal in size. Try to understand why this size difference and fix it.